# azure AKS internal load balancer not responding requests

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster, as well as a separate VM. AKS cluster and the VM are in the same VNET (as well as subnet).

I deployed a echo server with the following yaml, I'm able to directly curl the pod with vnet ip from the VM. But when trying that with load balancer, nothing returns. Really not sure what I'm missing. Any help is appreciated.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo-server
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: echo-server

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: echo-server
          image: ealen/echo-server
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
```

The following pictures demonstrate the situation
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm expecting that when curl the vnet ip from load balancer, to receive the same response as I did directly curling the pod ip

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution, the only thing I need to do is to add the following to the Service declaration:

```
externalTrafficPolicy: 'Local'
```

Full yaml as below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo-server
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: 'Local'
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: echo-server
```

previously it was set to 'Cluster'.

---

Just got off with azure support, seems like a specific bug on this (it happens with newer version of the AKS), posting the related link here: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/8501

Comment: I use this command helm upgrade if you are using ingress controller:
helm upgrade ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
  --reuse-values \
  --namespace <my-namespace> \
  --set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local

Answer (score 4):

Can you check your internal-loadbalancer health probe.

"For Kubernetes 1.24+ the services of type LoadBalancer with appProtocol HTTP/HTTPS will switch to use HTTP/HTTPS as health probe protocol (while before v1.24.0 it uses TCP). And / will be used as the default health probe request path. If your service doesn’t respond 200 for /, please ensure you're setting the service annotation service.beta.kubernetes.io/port_{port}_health-probe_request-path or service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path (applies to all ports) with the correct request path to avoid service breakage."
(ref: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/releases/tag/2022-09-11)

If you are using nginx-ingress controller, try adding the same as mentioned in doc:
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli#basic-configuration)

```
helm upgrade ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
  --reuse-values \
  --namespace <NAMESPACE> \
  --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether the pod's IP is correctly mapped as an endpoint to the service? You can check it using,

`k describe svc echo-server -n test | grep Endpoints`

If not please check label and selectors with your actual deployment (rather the resources put in the description).

If it is correctly mapped, are you sure that the VM you are using (**_@tester**) is under the correct subnet which should include the iLB IP;10.240.0.226 as well?

Comment: Hi Sahan, thank you for your answer.
1. I can confirm the service is correctly mapped to the pod's IP.
2. Both VM and the AKS is in the same subnet, since there's only one subnet under this vnet (10.240.0.0/16).